Media Queries Max-Width is not applied even though I am on mobile view (Browser)
I have a website in Astro and using SCSS.
I have a weird bug with the media queries.
I have this styling
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .p-content {
        &_inner {
            padding: rem(140) 10% rem(150);
        }
    }
}

This should be applied for smaller screen with a max-width of 768px.
For the rest I use
.p-content {
        &_inner {
            padding: rem(140) 30% rem(150);
        }

It works so far.
When I switch to the developer console and go to responsive view, the styling is applied correctly but when I change a device, the max-width style is not applied but the normal one.
I even tried to apply the setting only with a min-width of 1024px for example.
Even so, this styling is applied, even though the view is definitely below 1024px (no matter which width I take, always min-width: 1024px is applied).
Is this a bug from the browser?
I have this setting width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 already.
As you can see for example iPhone 12 Pro - I don't understand why
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .p-content_inner {
        padding: calc(140rem / 16) 30% calc(150rem / 16);
    }
}

is applied?
I created a code on code sandbox.
This problem also occurs for me.
I guess it has to be a bug on my browser?
Tested on chrome and edge.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/still-sun-hz2gxq?file=%2Findex.html


Can you share this code @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {     .p-content {&_inner { padding: rem(140) 10% rem(150);}}} for 1024px.

Which code exactly? The whole css code or the html?

Please provide a [mcve], with the emphasis on minimal

I added. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/still-sun-hz2gxq?file=%2Findex.html

Link does not work

Oh I am sorry, had to change  the visibility.. now it should work

Works fine for me. I see the media query is applied.

I realized on my phone it looks fine too. I guess it is my PC or browser maybe? If I change to other dimension for example iPad, it is somehow not applied
